# Using Cypress functions in different files

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to use cypress functions in files different from the main one (which is the test file). I am wondering if it is possible.
Actually, I did this: this is the code in my test.js file; note that the first function is what I'm trying to do; the second function works normally and I have no problem with that. The reason why I am trying to do that is that I could need to reuse the same function multiple times.

my tree folders:

```
static_copied
    pages
        cities
            Rome
            New York
            Bombay
            Tokyo
            London
            Moscow
```

`test.js` file:

```
const pathCities = 'static_copied/pages/cities'

it('Retrieve cities from static and divide links', () => {
      

      let cities1 = misc.retrieveCities()
      console.log(cities1)

      // this works
      cy.task('readFolder', pathCities).then(cities => {
        console.log('cities ', cities, typeof cities)    // prints an array of cities, and 'object'
      })
    })
  })
```

my `misc.help.js` file:

```
const pathCities = 'static_copied/pages/cities'

module.exports = {
    retrieveCities,
    [...]
}

[...]

function retrieveCities() {
  cy.task('readFolder', pathCities).then(res => {
    console.log('here', res, typeof res)
    return res
  })
}
```

and finally my `cypress/plugins/index.js` file:

```
const fs = require('fs')

// opens devTools by default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  [...]

  // reads a folder, both folder and file names
  on('task', {
    readFolder(path) {
      let foldersAnFiles = fs.readdirSync(path, 'utf8')
      console.log('--->', foldersAnFiles, typeof foldersAnFiles)

      let folders = []

      // if its a file, exclude from result
      foldersAnFiles.filter(function (folder) {
        if (folder.indexOf('.') === -1) {
          folders.push(folder)
        }
      })
      
      return folders
    },
  })
}
```

What happens is that in `misc.help.js` file, print is correct: in `retrieveCities()` function, this console log `console.log('here', res, typeof res)` correctly prints an array.
But when i return it in the main test file, `console.log(cities1)` prints `undefined`.

Is there a way to pass to the main file my result?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your commands file and it then call `cy.retrieveCities()` in any test file and it will work.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('retrieveCities', () => {
  return cy.task('readFolder', pathCities).then(res => {
    return res
  })
})
```